# Mapeamento objeto-relacional (JPA + Hibernate) usando XML

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, jpa

Por uma razão específica, preciso fazer o mapeamento objeto-relacional (JPA) das minhas entidades com XML.
[Infelizmente,] Não posso usar anotações para fazer isso. Acontece que, em certas propriedades, preciso usar features específicas do Hibernate. Por exemplo, extra lazy collections, algo que eu facilmente faria usando annotations com @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA).

A documentação do Hibernate JPA, diz o seguinte:

> "If you wish to use Hibernate specific features in some entities, you'll have to either use annotations or fallback to hbm files. You can of course mix and match annotated entities and entities describes in hbm files." (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/xml-overriding.html)

Acontece que eu não faço ideia como usar os citados "hbm files" junto com o meu orm.xml (se é que é isso que eu devo fazer).

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, hbm que eu me lembre, são apenas nomenclaturas específicas dos arquivos que hibernate usava para mapeamento... Então no seu caso por exemplo: orm.hbn.xml que no fim das contas ainda é seu orm.xml onde você define todo o mapeamento das entidades.

Só se atente à prioridade de configuração, seu arquivo xml irá fazer o override de definições deita através de annotations.